# outer apply issue: Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

Scenario:
I have a people table and I need to see if the person is in a registry and when they were first added into the registry.

Then, I have a visit table where the person could have any number of visits to a clinic or a hospital.

I want to see how many visits of each visit type they had in the 12 months prior to being added to the registry as well as a cumulative month-to-month of visits after they were added.  The premise is that the average number of visits will decrease over time.

I came up with this query in my head but then putting it to practice, mssql does not like the logic. Unfortunately, not many people on the Internet get this error message.  The only other idea I have is to have 13 outer applies which feels inelegant.

> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

I've tried applying some of the suggestions in other stackoverflow, such as joining to the rgstry on visits.person_id = rgstry.person_id within the outer apply.  With this, it just says it cannot find that outer rgstry table.

```
select

people_table.person_id
,rgstry.start_dttm
,cast(datediff(day,rgstry.start_dttm,getdate())/30.0 as float) as MonthsSinceEnrollment
,coalesce(visits_12m.clinic_12m_Before,0) as clinic_12m_Before
,coalesce(visits_12m.hospital_12m_Before,0) as hospital_12m_Before
,coalesce(visits_12m.clinic_1m_after,0) as clinic_1m_after
,coalesce(visits_12m.hospital_1m_after,0) as hospital_1m_after
,coalesce(visits_12m.clinic_2m_after,0) as clinic_2m_after
,coalesce(visits_12m.hospital_2m_after,0) as hospital_2m_after
--... thru 12 months after

from people_table

join
    (
    select registry.person_id, registry.start_dttm
    from registry
    where
    registry.registry_id = 12345    --ROSTER
    and registry.registry_status = '1' --active
    ) as rgstry on people_table.person_id = rgstry.person_id

outer apply
    (
    select visits.person_id
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between dateadd(month,-12, rgstry.start_dttm) and rgstry.start_dttm and visits.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_12m_Before
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between dateadd(month,-12, rgstry.start_dttm) and rgstry.start_dttm and visits.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_12m_Before
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,1,rgstry.start_dttm) and visits.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_1m_After
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,1,rgstry.start_dttm) and visits.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_1m_After
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,2,rgstry.start_dttm) and visits.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_2m_After
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,2,rgstry.start_dttm) and visits.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_2m_After
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,3,rgstry.start_dttm) and visits.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_3m_After
    ,sum(case when visits.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,3,rgstry.start_dttm) and visits.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_3m_After
    --... thru 12 months after

    from visits
    where
    people_table.person_id = visits.person_id
    and visits.visit_dttm >= dateadd(month,-12, rgstry.start_dttm) --get count of visits for preceding 12 months
    and visits.visit_dttm < dateadd(month,12, rgstry.start_dttm) --get count of visits 12 months following
    and visits.visit_type in
        (   
        'clinic'
        ,'hospital'         
        )
    group by visits.person_id
    ) as visits_12m
```

edit - this looks like it works

```
select

people_table.person_id
,rgstry.start_dttm
,cast(datediff(day,rgstry.start_dttm,getdate())/30.0 as float) as MonthsSinceEnrollment
,sum(case when visits_12m.visit_type = 'clinic' and visits_12m.visit_dttm between dateadd(month,-12, rgstry.start_dttm) and rgstry.start_dttm then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_12m_Before
,sum(case when visits_12m.visit_type = 'hospital' and visits_12m.visit_dttm between dateadd(month,-12, rgstry.start_dttm) and rgstry.start_dttm then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_12m_Before
,sum(case when visits_12m.visit_type = 'clinic' and visits_12m.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,1,rgstry.start_dttm) then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_1m_after
,sum(case when visits_12m.visit_type = 'hospital' and visits_12m.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,1,rgstry.start_dttm) then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_1m_after
,sum(case when visits_12m.visit_type = 'clinic' and visits_12m.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,2,rgstry.start_dttm) then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_2m_after
,sum(case when visits_12m.visit_type = 'hospital' and visits_12m.visit_dttm between rgstry.start_dttm and dateadd(month,2,rgstry.start_dttm) then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_2m_after
---.. thru 12 months after
from people_table

join
    (
    select registry.person_id, registry.start_dttm
    from registry
    where
    registry.registry_id = 12345    --ROSTER
    and registry.registry_status = '1' --active
    ) as rgstry on people_table.person_id = rgstry.person_id

left join
    (
    select visits.person_id,visits.visit_dttm ,visits.visit_type
    from visits
    where
    visits.visit_type in ('clinic','hospital')
    ) as visits_12m on people_table.person_id = visits_12m.person_id and datediff(month, rgstry.start_dttm, visits_12m.visit_dttm) between -12 and 12

group by

people_table.person_id
,rgstry.start_dttm
,cast(datediff(day,rgstry.start_dttm,getdate())/30.0 as float)
```

Comment: OUTER APPLY is dedicated to table function... "visits" seems to be a table not a function. Replace the OUTER APPLY by a join (INNER or OUTER).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I've used outer applies before with tables.  It's just when I referenced the 'rgstry' join within the aggregate statements of the outer apply that the error occurs.

If I use a join instead of outer apply, would I still be able to supply the visit join with a date range like this?  I guess I am not visualizing how that would look.

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
WITH 
PT AS 
(
SELECT registry.person_id, 
       registry.start_dttm, 
       people_table.person_id, 
       rgstry.start_dttm, 
       CAST(DATEDIFF(day, rgstry.start_dttm, GETDATE()) / 30.0 AS FLOAT) AS MonthsSinceEnrollment, 
       COALESCE(visits_12m.clinic_12m_Before, 0) AS clinic_12m_Before, 
       COALESCE(visits_12m.hospital_12m_Before, 0) AS hospital_12m_Before, 
       COALESCE(visits_12m.clinic_1m_after, 0) AS clinic_1m_after, 
       COALESCE(visits_12m.hospital_1m_after, 0) AS hospital_1m_after, 
       COALESCE(visits_12m.clinic_2m_after, 0) AS clinic_2m_after, 
       COALESCE(visits_12m.hospital_2m_after, 0) AS hospital_2m_after
--... thru 12 months after
FROM   people_table
       JOIN registry 
          ON people_table.person_id = rgstry.person_id
WHERE  registry.registry_id = 12345    --ROSTER
       AND registry.registry_status = '1' --active
),
VS AS
(
SELECT visits.person_id, visits.visit_dttm, visit_type
FROM   visits
       JOIN PT AS people_table 
          ON people_table.person_id = visits.person_id
WHERE  visits.visit_dttm >= dateadd(month,-12, rgstry.start_dttm) --get count of visits for preceding 12 months
       and visits.visit_dttm < dateadd(month,12, rgstry.start_dttm) --get count of visits 12 months following
       and visits.visit_type in (   'clinic'    ,'hospital' )
)
select VS.person_id
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between dateadd(month,-12, PTstart_dttm) and PTstart_dttm and VS.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_12m_Before
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between dateadd(month,-12, PTstart_dttm) and PTstart_dttm and VS.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_12m_Before
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between PTstart_dttm and dateadd(month,1,PTstart_dttm) and VS.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_1m_After
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between PTstart_dttm and dateadd(month,1,PTstart_dttm) and VS.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_1m_After
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between PTstart_dttm and dateadd(month,2,PTstart_dttm) and VS.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_2m_After
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between PTstart_dttm and dateadd(month,2,PTstart_dttm) and VS.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_2m_After
    ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between PTstart_dttm and dateadd(month,3,PTstart_dttm) and VS.visit_type = 'hospital' then 1 else 0 end) as clinic_3m_After
       ,sum(case when VS.visit_dttm between PTstart_dttm and dateadd(month,3,PTstart_dttm) and VS.visit_type = 'clinic' then 1 else 0 end) as hospital_3m_After
    --... thru 12 months after
FROM  PT
      JOIN VS
         ON PT.person_id = VS.person_id
GROUP  BY VS.person_id
```

Comment: can you take a look at my edit above?  I tried using a left join instead of outer apply and did the aggregation on the main query and it looks like it solves it

Comment: without the complete description of your tables (colums and constraints) and a set of data inserted into the tables, and an example of result, it is very difficult to answer yes or no ton your question... Just do some complémentary test to proove it. But remember that APPLY must not be used for table. Yes you can but it is an "anti pattern" that that a few people use and master in very specific cases (an equivalent of the CROSS JOIN when the table has always a low cardinality)